# solution to cube root of finite field

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, cubics

I'm trying to solve the following equation and I'm having trouble

$$y^3 = (x)^e \pmod n $$

in my case $x^e = 124205, n = 129071$

I'm expecting this answer to result in $65$ (as this is the thing that went into the equation to begin with) however I can't seem to figure out how to solve the cube root of this modulo equation.

Comment: We have $129071=337\times 383$ so you can just solve the problem with respect to the two smaller primes and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to build the answer $\pmod n$.

Comment: The point of the RSA encryption scheme is like this.  Doing the third power is much easier than doing the cube root.  In fact, unless you can factor $129071$ it will be very hard to solve your problem.

Comment: The solutions are $y \equiv 16630,19694,24673 \bmod 129071$ according to  [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E3+%3D+124205+mod129071)